# pr2_navigation_slam rviz_move_base_slam.launch 2d nav goal

Tags: slam, navigation, rviz, slam-gmapping, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
I'm trying to build a map on a PR2, and am not able to move the robot via the rviz "2D Nav Goal". Here are the steps I've taken:

-on the PR2:
$roslaunch pr2_2dnav_slam pr2_2dnav.launch

-on another computer:
$roslaunch pr2_navigation_slam rviz_move_base_slam.launch

-try to set nav goal:
This does not move the robot. Setting "rostopic echo move_base_simple/goal" on both the PR2 and rviz computers shows that the "move_base_simple/goal" message is being sent (ie, message shows up on both machines), but for some reason does not result in any actual movement. It almost seems like the move_base node isn't subscribed to the "move_base_simple/goal" topic.

Any help is greatly appreciated.
Evan

EDIT:
This turned out to be a hostname issue, where the machine sending the message wasn't being properly resolved.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11672/pr2_navigation_slam-rviz_move_base_slam.launch-2d-nav-goal/) by [evan](https://answers.ros.org/users/1278/evan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2011-10-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This turned out to be a hostname issue, where the machine sending the message wasn't being properly resolved.

---

Originally posted by [evan](https://answers.ros.org/users/1278/evan/) with karma: 41 on 2012-01-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [NikolasEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/652/nikolasengelhard/) on 2012-03-15**:
Could you say a bit more about your problem and how you solved it? I currently have the same problem on our PR2.